# can I upload photos through mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, data-transfer, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to upload files to a website from Safari on iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4104/is-it-possible-to-upload-files-to-a-website-from-safari-on-iphone)

I am designing a website. I want users to be able to upload photos from their iPhone to my website, as such I need to know:

**Can users upload from their phone gallery through Mobile Safari to my site?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not, if the phone is not jailbroken.